Can polkit recognize per-host admin rights based on LDAP (FreeIPA) sudo rule
Our users are managed through FreeIPA, and each workstation has a sudo rule configured so that the user has sudo privileges on their assigned workstation. This can be verified on the workstation by running the command "sudo -ll -U ". However, since the user is not assigned to the local sudo group or an LDAP admin group, they are unable to perform elevated tasks (install software via Software Center, etc.) in the graphical environment. Instead of prompting for the password of the logged-in user trying to perform the task, the "Requires authentication" window prompts for the password of a user in either the LDAP sudo group or local sudo group. Is there a way to write a rule or conf file that can detect that a user's authorization comes from an LDAP rule and not membership in a group?
I can assign the user to the local group on their specific workstation and it will work. I can write a conf file (in /etc/polkig-1/localauthority.conf.d/) with the user "hard-coded" in the file, both of which work - tested by running "pkexec bash" and observing the list of users allowed to elevate to run the command - but neither is feasible when managing a large number of users that rotate on a regular basis.
